# I want to be able to to pull through the previous school in which a pupil left to start a new school? (Lookup function)

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2019

In our database, there is a list of schools which a pupil attends over their lifespan. I have attached a photo below to show how it structured whilst cropping out the confidentiality bits.

[image]

I have already got a main dataset where specific information needs to go and 'historical school name' needs to be in another dataset.

Therefore I need to do a lookup function to bring the historical school name into the report as such:
"=lookup(Fields!Child_ID__System_Ref_.Value, Fields!Child_ID__System_Ref_.Value, Fields!School_Details_Name.Value, "Attendance_Data")"

The problem is that it brings any random school in no logical order through. I need the latest previous school they attended before the school they now attend. I have no idea how to do this as there is no ID number or anything.

The only way I can think of it is using the dates they attended the school and doing an expression which says directly before the new school they started. They won't have an 'End Date' at the school they're currently attending.

Comment: Why have you tagged SSRS 2005, 2008 and 2012? Are you really using all 3 of those versions? Why are you using versions that are *completely* unsupported or close to be?

Comment: Hi Larnu, I am trying to get as much exposure for my problem as possible as I would like some help. I will be using the latest version of SRSS if you have come to help?

Comment: *"I am trying to get as much exposure for my problem as possible"* Tagging the *wrong* versions/products doesn't help you get exposure, it's more likely your question will be ignored. Especially when you tag a version of SSRS that has had no support in over 5 years; even the best of us can't remember what functionality was and wasn't in that versions, as most of us probably haven't used it in the best part of a decade.

Comment: Thanks for your help Larnu! Great use of time :-)

Comment: if your looking for the max in SSRS lookup, i suggest you use code in report to aggregate result, [Here's](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9eaded10-debf-471a-ab77-6f58b4826b54/combine-seperate-lookupsets-find-max-count?forum=sqlreportingservices) a link containing examples on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, I would do this directly in your dataset query.

I've mocked up some sample data based on your sample (and added another child)

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (ChildID int, SchoolID int, StartDate date, EndDate Date)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
(1, 10, '2011-07-18', '2011-09-07'),
(1, 20, '2011-09-08', '2019-07-19'),
(1, 30, '2019-09-02', '2021-11-30'),
(1, 40, '2021-12-01', NULL),
(2, 20, '2012-07-18', '2012-09-07'),
(2, 40, '2012-09-08', '2018-07-19'),
(2, 60, '2018-09-02', '2020-11-30'),
(2, 80, '2020-12-01', NULL)

    SELECT 
        *
        , LAG(SchoolID, 1, NULL) OVER(PARTITION BY ChildID ORDER BY StartDate) AS PreviousSchoolID
        FROM @t t
```

Then I simply used the `LAG()` function to get the previous school. This gives the following results

[image]

If you only need the current and previous school then you can wrap the final select statement as a sub query and then select only rows with no EndDate

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        *
        , LAG(SchoolID, 1, NULL) OVER(PARTITION BY ChildID ORDER BY StartDate) AS PreviousSchoolID
        FROM @t t 
    ) h WHERE EndDate IS NULL
```

which would give this result.

[image]